# How to spend from a custom P2SH script using bitcore-lib

Tags: p2sh, bitcore, javascript

My Javascript/typescript project uses bitcore-lib. It uses `Script.buildScriptHashOut` to build custom P2SH outputs. How do I spend from this custom output?

Answer (score 0):

I could not find anywhere on the web about it. I was hopeless until I noticed that I could, without modifying the library.

First choose a similar class in [Bitcore-lib](https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore/tree/master/packages/bitcore-lib/lib/transaction/input).

- [multisigscripthash](https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore/blob/master/packages/bitcore-lib/lib/transaction/input/multisigscripthash.js) (<== suggested) or publickeyhash for P2SH outputs
- multisig or publickey for bare script outputs (don't use these, these are nonstandard)

Then copy it to a new file in your project such as [this one**](https://github.com/simpleledger/BitcoinFilesJS/blob/d36aa7b76b3cc137ae600fe08e73573874a13f9d/lib/pushoutput.ts). Do not use typescript classes even if your project is of kind Typescript.

Then change `require` paths. Also require `inherit` from NPM. As in the boilerplates above, we need to inherit from `Transaction.Input`

A function such as "buildP2SHPushIn" in the example should produce the redeemscript. Remember, the last element of P2SH redeem scripts is a push of the P2SH script.

And finally use `addInput` instead of the higher-level function `from` to add inputs as [shown here**](https://github.com/simpleledger/BitcoinFilesJS/blob/d36aa7b76b3cc137ae600fe08e73573874a13f9d/lib/bfp.ts#L412-L430)

---

**The examples are for Bitcoin Cash, but they can be used the same way in Bitcoin. Do not copy from them, however!

Comment: If the examples are for bcash or similar forks of Bitcoin, I would be careful in using them for Bitcoin or use a different library considering incidents like https://www.reddit.com/r/bsv/comments/jq9jv3/and_its_gone_popular_bsv_multisig_provides_no/

Comment: Well, the boilerplates listed in "First choose a similar class in Bitcore." are for BTC so I hope my answer is more useful than it is dangerous. I wasn't aware of that incident